# 雨を降っています - grammatically correct sentence or just typo?

Tags: particle-を, transitivity

It seems that there are around 14-17K Google results on each of "[雨を降って](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E9%9B%A8%E3%82%92%E9%99%8D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%22)" and "[雪を降って](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E9%9B%AA%E3%82%92%E9%99%8D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%22)" keywords. Is 降る yet another intransitive verb that are used with を? Does it mean something like "rain on me" and "snow on me", or is it simply typo?

Some sample usages taken from Google results:

- 今夜雨を降っている
- 雨を降っても傘ささないのが仇となった
- 沢山の雪を降っているの画像

N.B. I don't think [either "through" or "leaving something behind" interpretations](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/making-sense-of-transitive-usage-of-and-and) can work with "を降る".

Comment: With respect to your `雨を降って` link, the first one is written by a Chinese, the second one by some student from abroad, and the third one by a Chinese, the fourth looks like an overlooked computer translation error. I didn't feel like looking any further. In all of them, it is not just the sentence you mentioned that is wrong. The whole paragraphs are broken Japanese. You should be careful about the quality of your source.

Comment: @sawa Oops, sorry. I guess I should have looked deeper into the results. >____<

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo and based on inaccurate Google results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say it's a typo, but 17K Google results is hard to compete against.  It may be incorrect grammar that gets "accepted" as correct and becomes incorporated into the language.  Correct grammar would be:

- `雨は・が降る`　→　"It's raining" or
- `雨を降らす`　→　"Make it rain" (if someone/thing could cause rain -- like God, a spirit, character in a story, etc.)

Comment: Allow me to help with those 17k results: ["雪を降って"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E9%9B%AA%E3%82%92%E9%99%8D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%22&hl=en&start=100), 104 results; ["雨を降って"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E9%9B%A8%E3%82%92%E9%99%8D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%22&hl=en&start=180), 170 results. (May look slightly different for you??) [Google result counts are a meaningless metric](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/google-result-counts-are-a-meaningless-metric.html). I wish Google would warn more prominently about this on the results page; it's a common misconception.

Comment: I'm sure I can find a crapload of bad English via Google as well. 9.2M search results for "a apple" in quotation marks, including one to a link to an American movie of a native English speaker saying it. That doesn't make it grammatically correct.