# In which situations is が used with 曲がる?

Tags: particles

According to jmdict 曲がる is intransitive, therefore it should be used with が or は. However it always seems to be used with を - for example:
この道を行って二つ目の角を右に曲がります。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is related to a pattern with "motion verbs" in Japanese that are considered to be intransitive, but still use を to describe the area that the motion goes through.

From the first part of your example, この道を行って, the を in this case marks the area or thing through which the subjects 'goes', even though it's not a transitive verb. Often this use of を can be described as "along X" or "through X", and often carries the implication of moving along or through either all or a significant portion of the area described with を.

The same is true of 曲がります in your example, and it means something like "turn through that corner". Another example would be 飛行機が空を飛ぶ.

が simply marks the subject of the sentence, the thing that is moving through the corner or along the street, or through the sky. (I suspect your question title meant to reference を instead of が, however, given that your example sentence does not contain the particle が)

Comment: To supplement this, reference this post too:  http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3243/78

Comment: Thanks. I knew that you could use を for 行く and 出る but i was not sure that you could also use this for 曲がる. Does it mean that as long as something describes "motion along something" it is possible to use を? Thats what i uderstood from the link by @istrasci.

Comment: @OlegLevy: Pretty much any verb involving motion: 散歩, 行く, 出る, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That sentence basically boils down to `（私・あなた・someone）（は・が）...角を曲がります。`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken shouldn't 曲がります work like　分かります, since they are both intransitive？　Where the object takes が　not を.

Comment: No, it is a motion `を` as @jkerian explains in his/her answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason here is very simple.

The 角 is not what is doing/being 曲がる, 角 is simply the medium that the action is being preformed through.

Take the following similar example, 電車{でんしゃ}が線路{せんろ}を走{はし}る.

As in my example, your sentence has the car/driver/etc doing the action, while the conner, road, etc is what is being acted on.