# Why is this で wrong, and を preferable? 「信号を左です」

Tags: grammar, particle-を, conjunctions, copula

## 日本語

知り合いに道案内していた時に、

> 次の信号**で**、左です

と言ったら、

> 次の信号**を**、左です

という言い方のほうがいいと言われました。

「です」は本物の動詞ではありませんし、「を」と繋がっているのは間違いではないのでしょうか。**省略された動詞がある**という分析のほうがいいのですか？そして、どうして「で」はだめなのですか？

## English

While giving an acquaintance driving directions, I said:

> 次の信号**で**、左です

but they corrected me, saying that:

> 次の信号**を**、左です

is preferable.

です is not a real verb, so thinking that を links to it would be a mistake, wouldn't it?  It seems like the view that **there is an implicit (abbreviated out) verb** is probably a better parsing. Is this correct?  Also, why is で incorrect in this case?

Comment: これを参考にして：http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5412/in-which-situations-is-%E3%81%8C-used-with-%E6%9B%B2%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/making-sense-of-transitive-usage-of-%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F-and-%E6%9D%A5%E3%82%8B-%E3%82%92%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F-and-%E3%82%92%E6%9D%A5%E3%82%8B

Comment: 「で」でもいいような気がしますが…。参考までに：https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/280616 意味がちょっと違うという意見も：http://alcom.alc.co.jp/questions/show/17976

Comment: If you regard movement of the car as something that unilaterally flows along with a scheduled course, then で feels fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 日本語

もうおっしゃったように

> 「次の信号を左」、「前の角を右」

云々は、肝要なところが抜けているだけだと存じます。
本来なら完全な文書では、

> 次の信号を左。。。**に曲がります**
> 前の角を右。。。**に曲がって**ください

まで言いますが、省略してしまうのが一般的ですね。

下記のように：

- 「図書館の前を歩く」
- 「空を飛ぶ」

「曲がる」・「飛ぶ」・「歩く」・「走る」のような「移動性」のある動詞の対象となる語をよく「を」でマークします。

それで、**「で」は何故だめなのかについては**、勘で言っているだけですが、「で」を**移動動詞**と使うと、「で」の「手段」を指定する機能を先に考えてしまうからではないでしょうか？

例えば、

> 道**を**歩く
> 道**で**歩く

道では歩けるが、運河では歩けませんよね。まぁ、両方いけるんじゃない？

然し！

- 飛行機で空を飛ぶ

手段も動作の領域も指定されていますね。これが移動動詞の特徴だと思います。移動動詞なら、場所を「を」で、手段を「で」で指定します。

それで、

> 信号**で**曲がる

とはどういう意味になるかを考えますと、ちょっと変だと分かりますね。

### 「です」の役割

「です」は、その「どこそこに曲がる」というところを取って代わっている気がします。運転手が「どちらへ曲がればいいでしょうか」を考‌​えているのを前提にすると、部分的に答えたら自然と「次の信号を」・「左です」になるでしょうね。あたかも運転手が考えていることをもう既に空気で読んだかのようにですね。‌​

空気を読めずに完全に言うと

> 「次に信号を曲がってください。左です。」

になるかと思います。

### 「次の信号で左です」の場合

接続的に「で」を使‌​うのもあり得る発言だとおもいますが、「次の信号であって、左です」という意味になるでしょうかね。トピックがその信号で、「左側です」まで言ったらあり得るかもしれません‌​けどね。

### 「次の信号は左です」の場合

「は」の使ったほうがよくあると思います。でも、単品でちょっと紛らわしく感じます。
「次の信号は左にあります」というふうに捉える可能性が高いから。

## English

As you've already said, I also think that

> 「次の信号を左」、「前の角を右」

is just dropping the verb.

In a full sentence it would probably look like this:

> 次の信号を左。。。**に曲がります**
> 前の角を右。。。**に曲がって**ください

But most people wouldn't bother to say all of that, probably because the context of being in a car makes it painfully obvious :)

So in the following examples...

- 「図書館の前を歩く」
- 「空を飛ぶ」

「曲がる」・「飛ぶ」・「歩く」・「走る」are part of a class of verbs that describe movement *through a space* and are often referred to as「移動動詞」, or Movement Verbs.

These verbs are usually used with 「を」.

**So, why would using 「で」be wrong** in the case that you mentioned in the OP?
Just speaking from how I perceive it, when you use 「で」with an 移動動詞, you're specifying the means you use to accomplish the action of movement.

For instance,

> 道**を**歩く
> 道**で**歩く

Both of these *could* be OK...

> 「道では歩けるが、運河では歩けませんよね。」

```
"You know you can walk on a road, but not on a canal."
```

However! In the case of the following...

> 飛行機で空を飛ぶ

```
fly in the sky with an airplane
```

The location that the action of movement takes place（sky・空）*and* the means of accomplishing that action（airplane・飛行機）are both specified. This is a prominent feature of 移動動詞. They use **を to specify location** and **で to specify means of movement**.

Soooo... If you think about what the following sentence would mean,

> 信号**で**曲がる

it's kind of strange, right?

### The role of 「です」

In this case です is replacing the usage of 曲がる. It's as if the driver has already said "Where would you like me to turn?" out-loud.
You would "answer" in sentence fragments about what he's just "asked", leaving out what he's already made clear, which is that "turning" is involved.

If you were to make the full request without assuming anything, you might say...

> 「次に信号を曲がってください。左です。」

```
"Please turn at the next signal. Left."
```

### What about 「次の信号で左です」?

It is possible to use で in this way, but it may be a little confusing because it could easily be taken as meaning...

> 「次の信号であって、左です。」

```
It's the next signal, left.
```

This seems to imply that you were already talking about a particular signal with the driver and you want to say that that signal is on the left side.

### What about 「次の信号は左です」?

I think people use は like this often. However, as an utterance just by itself it could be a little confusing because it could easily be taken to mean something like...

> 「次の信号は左にあります。」

```
The next signal is on the left.
```

Comment: I also posted an English version of this, but I don't know what happened to it. Can somebody help me restore it?

Comment: 探したけど、残ってないみたいです。。　http://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/36208/revisions　一瞬見たんですけどね・・

Comment: 見つかった！まだブラウザのキャッシュに残っていた。。。

Comment: どうしたら英語のところだけに追加できるか教えて頂けますでしょうか？

Comment: 私もやったことないんですけど、最初のところに「#日本語」 、「#English」って書いて、改行するみたいです。多分こんな感じ　http://japanese.stackexchange.com/revisions/e444d8a6-3806-4ad8-a333-2dec9ec50fb1/view-source

Comment: 「次の信号で、左」とすれば、そうですよね。ですが、もともとは「次の信号で、左です」でした。その「です」を回答に単純すぎるように入れてしまえば、「次の信号を左に曲がりますです」となりますが…どうやって「曲がる」を「です」と一緒に入れますか？または、動詞がなければ、「です」だけの場合、「信号で左です」とか「信号は左です」などという言い方は変ですか？

Comment: 一緒入れちゃだめだだかと思います。「です」は、その「どこそこに曲がる」というところを取って代わっている気がします。運転手が「どちらへ曲がればいいでしょうか」を考えているのを前提にすると、部分的に答えたら自然と「次の信号を」・「左です」になるでしょうね。あたかも運転手が考えていることをもう既に空気で読んだかのようにですね。そういうふうに小生は考えておりましたが、WeirdlyCheezyさんは如何でしょうか？

Comment: なるほど。「次の信号を、左です」というのは、省略されたの前に、二つの文章の「次に信号を曲がってください。左です。」だったという事になりますよね。

Comment: その通りだと思います。(*pun intended) :P

Comment: 笑。　ありがとうございます。と、動詞なしの場合、「次の信号で左です」（手段の「で」じゃなくて接続の「で」だったら）や「次の信号は左です」などは、文法的に間違えたのですか？それとも、大丈夫だけど余り使わないのですか？

Comment: 「は」の使ったほうがよくあると思います。でも、単品でちょっと紛らわしく感じます。「次の信号は左にあります」というふうに捉える可能性が高いから。接続的に「で」を使うのもあり得る発言だとおもいますが、「次の信号であって、左です」という意味になるでしょうかね。トピックがその信号で、「左側です」まで言ったらあり得るかもしれませんけどね。

Comment: 勉強になります。二つの文章の事と最後のコメの内容を回答に追加していただけませんか？そういう回答をAcceptしたいと思います

Comment: @WeirdlyCheezy 追加の解答は正しくないですよ。

Comment: @user4092 正しくない点を教えて頂けますか？