# Difference between だと vs と before 認める

Tags: nuances, copula, auxiliaries

> そのため、税務上の課税所得の計算は、「一般に公正妥当と認められる企業の基準」に基づく収益・費用の認識を原則としながらも、一定の調整を加えることとなっています。

I'm wondering what the difference is between

> 公正妥当と認められる

and

> 公正妥当だと認められる

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sub>(Basically I agree with goldbrick, but I think I should post my own answer...)</sub>

> 1. 一般に公正妥当と認められる企業の基準
> 2. 一般に公正妥当だと認められる企業の基準

Despite mackygoo's statement, in my opinion, both 公正妥当と認められる and 公正妥当だと認められる are perfectly fine, and neither is better or more natural than the other. There is no significant difference in meaning, either. Still, according to [BCCWJ](http://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/) (online free corpus), `na-adj/noun + と認める` is far more common than `na-adj/noun + だと認める`. You can find lots of examples without だ, including 相当と‌​認める, 重要と認める, 適切と認める, 本人と認める, 不当と認める, many of which are used in legal contexts. There are only a few examples of `na-adj + だと認める`.

[NHK's article about だ抜き](https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/term/140.html) is interesting, but it's about "**quotative**-と", where the part before と is a clause including more than one word. In such cases, people tend to add だ.

> - [○]明日**は**晴れ**だと**思う。　[?]明日**は**晴れ**と**思う。
> - [○]彼の名前**は**田中**だと**勘違いした。　[?]彼の名前**は**田中**と**勘違いした。
> - [○]彼**が**実は無実**だと**認めてください。　[?]彼**が**実は無実**と**認めてください。
> - [○]私は、彼女**は**英雄**だと**見なしている。　[?]私は、彼女**は**英雄**と**見なしている。
> - [○]自分の意見**は**常に正解**だと**思い込む。　[?]自分の意見**は**常に正解**と**思い込む。
>
> (○: fine, ?: questionable/clumsy/unnatural/highly-colloquial/etc)

In these cases, ones without だ look more or less clumsy to me, because the part before と is essentially a sentence with a verb and a corresponding subject.

However, と has another function which may not be "quotative". When と is used **in combination with を** and a certain type of verb, it works like "as". Recently I made [an (incomplete) list of such verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55169/5010). In such cases, the part before と is basically a single word (noun or na-adjective), and you can safely omit (or sometimes you *should* omit) だ!

> - [○]彼の名前**を**田中**だと**勘違いした。　[○]彼の名前**を**田中**と**勘違いした。
> - [○]彼**を**無実**だと**認めてください。　[○]彼**を**無実**と**認めてください。
> - [○]自分の意見**を**常に正解**だと**思い込む。　[○]自分の意見**を**常に正解**と**思い込む。
> - [○]私は、彼女**を**英雄**だと**見なしている。　[○]私は、彼女**を**英雄**と**見なしている。
> - [?]2直線の交点**を**P**だと**定義する。　[○]2直線の交点**を**P**と**定義する。

See the difference?

Now, back to your case, 一般に公正妥当(だ)と認められる企業の基準 can be seen as a relative clause made from (人が)企業の基準**を**公正妥当(だ)と認められる. Therefore だ in your original sentence is safely omitted. If you're dealing with some stiff legal material, it may be even better to drop this だ, according to the statistical evidence based on BCCWJ.

(Disclaimer: This may not be the only case where だ before と can be safely dropped. And as you can see, the level of acceptance may vary from verb to verb, from person to person. When in doubt, it's always a good idea to consult a corpus.)

Comment: NHKの例とＯＰの例とで「と」の前の部分が文節であるかどうかの違いを明確にした上での説明は明確であり、分かりやすく、見事です。（+1 upvote）

Comment: (^ 「文節」じゃなくて「節」だけどね...)

Comment: 辞書でも「発言や思考の内容を示す、いわゆる引用のト」と「動作や作用の結果を表す普通の格助詞としてのト」は明確に区別されており、この質問で問題となっているのは後者ですね。「娘を花子と名付ける」なども、ダが入るとむしろ奇妙になる例だと思います。

Answer (score 8):

The omission of the copula だ before a と meaning "as" is grammatically permitted, and common. And since the だ mostly serves a grammatical function, the meaning remains effectively the same after dropping it. (Consider "be recognized as equitable and fair" and "be recognized as being equitable and fair", to the extent that these mean the same thing.) I don't see any difference in formality, either.

Comment: I agree that, in this particular case, だ can be safely omitted without changing the meaning a bit. I was unsure when you can safely drop だ, but maybe you can do so if it is used with [this type of verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55169/5010). 彼が犯人と思い込む sounds a little clumsy/informal, but 彼を犯人と思い込む sounds perfectly fine, at least to me.

Comment: Yeah, I think the acceptability of  だ-omission depends on the complement structure the verb takes. If the verb takes a finite clause like "AがBだ" the omission of だ feels distinctly colloquial and therefore awkward in formal/written language. When it takes "noun object + predicate" like "AをBだ" the omission feels perfectly good in both informal and formal contexts.

Answer (score 0):

## English

> (A) 公正妥当と認められる
> (B) 公正妥当**だ**と認められる

I think (A) is a kind of "だ抜｛ぬ｝き言葉｛ことば｝".
With regard to "だ抜き言葉", the explanation by NHK is [here](https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/term/140.html).
I feel that (A) is considerably more natural than the following examples of "だ抜き言葉" mentioned in NHK's commentary.

> - フランスは大丈夫と思って成田まで来たので残念です。
> - 高さ数十センチ程度だから大丈夫と思わずに…
> - 誰からも立派と思われる横綱になってほしい。
> - 高齢の母親の面倒が大変と思い…

Still, I think that (B) is more natural than (A).
I think that (A) seems to be used in a certain official document, but I think that there are many cases where the expression with (C) is used instead of (A) in official documents. In these cases, I like (C) better than (B).

> (C) 公正妥当**である**と認められる

For (A), I wrote that it was "a kind of ら抜きことば" , because I didn't know whether (A) derived from (C) was also called "ら抜き言葉".

user27280 wrote in the answer, which has already been deleted by himself/herself, that 公正妥当 in (A) had the possibility of (D) or (E) . If I reinforce the answer, I think that it can be paraphrased as (F) or (G).

> (D) 公正妥当(されている) ⇒ (F) 公正妥当**性が**認められている
> (E) 公正妥当(がある) ⇒ (G) 公正妥当**性がある**と認められる

## 日本語

> (A) 公正妥当と認められる
> (B) 公正妥当**だ**と認められる

(A)は「だ抜き言葉」の一種だと思います。
「だ抜き言葉」につきましては、ＮＨＫによる説明が[ここ](https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/term/140.html)にあります。

(A)は、ＮＨＫの説明に挙{あ}がっている以下に引用する「だ抜き言葉」の例よりかなり自然に感じます。

> - フランスは大丈夫と思って成田まで来たので残念です。
> - 高さ数十センチ程度だから大丈夫と思わずに…
> - 誰からも立派と思われる横綱になってほしい。
> - 高齢の母親の面倒が大変と思い…

それでも、私は、(A)よりも(B)の方がより自然であると思います。
なお、(A)は公式の文章の中で使われているように思いますが、私は公式の文章では(A)の代わりに(C)の表現を用いる場合も多くあるように思います。私はこの場合、(B)より(C)の方が好きです。

> (C) 公正妥当**である**と認められる

(A)に対して、「だ抜き言葉の一種」だと書きましたのは、その理由は、私は(C)が(A)になることも「だ抜き言葉」というかどうか知らないからです。

user27280さんが(D)(E)の可能性を回答しておりました（既にこの回答はご自身により消されております）が、その回答を補強するなら、(F)あるいは(G)のように言い換えられるようにも思います。

> (D) 公正妥当(されている) ⇒ (F) 公正妥当**性が**認められている
> (E) 公正妥当(がある) ⇒ (G) 公正妥当**性がある**と認められる

Comment: The link might be a red herring. It seems to me that the と's in the NHK examples (except the one with "立派")  work like the subordinator "that" (as in "I think that...") and the と at issue here like "as", though I admit the line can get blurry in some cases. (I think said  line can be drawn rather clearly between "その企業が公正妥当(だ)と認める" and "その企業を公正妥当(だ)と認める".)   My impression is that a だ before a subordinating と is less omission-friendly than one before a と that function like "as".

Comment: (B)の方が(A)より自然だという意見には全く同意できません。私は(A)の文は全く問題ないと思います。現にBCCWJで眺める限り、「と認める」の前に形容動詞か名詞が来る例の少なくとも9割以上は「相当と認める」「重要と認める」「適切と認める」「本人と認める」「不当と認める」といった感じの『だ抜き』であり、(B)のような表現の方が遙かにマイナーです。もちろんNHKの説明はそれはそれで良いのですが、この質問の例とは条件が違いますし、その条件まで考察しないと適切な回答にならないと思います。

Comment: ご高説痛み入りますが、「BCCWJで9割以上」というのはご自身で無料で1分で確認できる客観的事実であり、私の感性などという曖昧なものに依拠した話ではないことは認識してください。私は自分の感性をそこまで信用していないので、客観的な証拠を使って反駁しています。自身の感性を信じ切っているのは、むしろ貴方の方では…。（長くなってもしょうがないので自分の回答も書きます…）