# grammatical and semantic difference of "嘘と思う" and "嘘だと思う"

Tags: meaning

Before I move on to the topic, here is my analysis based on my grammar book:

> これを**嬉しい**と思う。
>
> これを**親切だ**と思う。

The bolded part are quotation (引用), and the と behaves as a 格助詞 (quotation particle).

> これを**嬉しく**思う。
>
> これを**親切に**思う。

The bolded part are adverbial phrases.

Following this logic, I conclude that

> これを**嘘だ**と思う。　→quotation (引用)
>
> これを**嘘と**思う。　　→adverbial phrases

Hopefully someone could comment on my analysis, and more importantly, the difference of their usage. I mean, the situation when the two sentences are not interchangeable. One Japanese told me that the two sentences have little difference and can be used interchangeably, but I wonder if there is any exception.

Feel free to add more/change words to make the sentence sound more natural, 違和感がない.
For instance, 「**それをうそと思う**かはあなた次第だ」

"当然のことと思う"/"当然のことだと思う" is another pair where I have the same question.

Comment: Related (or duplicate) https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/56003/9831

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the verb you're using. For many verbs, `AをBとV` and `AをBだとV` are completely interchangeable. (I may be wrong, but maybe だ tends to be dropped more often if it's in either highly-casual speech or a highly-stiff written document.)

- それを嘘と思う = それを嘘だと思う
- それを嘘と見なす = それを嘘だと見なす
- それを嘘と考える = それを嘘だと考える
- それを嘘と仮定する = それを嘘だと仮定する

But you cannot add だ at least for these verbs:

- 娘を花子と名付ける (×娘を花子だと名付ける)
- これをゼータ関数と定義する (×これをゼータ関数だと定義する)
- 人はそれを愛と呼ぶ (×人はそれを愛だと呼ぶ)

I can't explain well why. Recently @DariusJahandarie introduced me an article exactly regarding this topic, so I hope it helps you too:

[Tsuyoshi Sawada, *Da*-Deletion: Classification of Clause-Final Elements in Japanese](http://www.ic.nanzan-u.ac.jp/LINGUISTICS/publication/pdf/NLSI3_2-8-sawada.pdf), Nanzan Linguistics: Special Issue 3, Vol. 2, 139–163 (PDF)

Section 8, On The Ambiguity of *To*, seems to be particularly related. But I haven't read them all, and note that some examples marked with `*` (incorrect) actually look okay to me. Particularly, the author says `AをBと思った` is wrong (see (66)), but I don't think so.

Comment: えっ　コネチカット州のさわだつよしさんて・・・・

Comment: @Schokolade えっ？

Comment: The difference between the first and the second group of verbs seems quite logical and intuitive to me. The first group relate to the subject’s own ‘inner’ considerations/views of what X’s attributes _are_, whereas the latter group relate to _assigning_ attributes to X. The same distinction holds for English: we can consider/view/suppose _X to be Y_ or _that X is Y_, but we cannot name/define/call _*X to be Y_ or _*that X is Y_ (actually, we can _define X to be Y_, but that’s an infinitive of purpose, semantically different from the one in _consider X to be Y_).