# How to analyze the structure of this sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntax

> 私たちの会社は、従業員のうち、エンジニアは、技術力を持つ重要な存在であるとし、経営の基盤として認めている。

My own analysis is:
1.In this sentence, 「とし」is the continuative form of 「とする」.
2.the phrase before 「とし」 should be seen as a clause， which means the structure should be

> 私たちの会社は、(従業員のうち、エンジニアは、技術力を持つ重要な存在である)とし、経営の基盤として認めている。

and the subject of 「し」and「認めている」 is 「私たちの会社」.
3.We can divide the whole sentence into 2 parts:

> 私たちの会社は、(従業員のうち、エンジニアは、技術力を持つ重要な存在である)とする
> 私たちの会社は、経営の基盤として認めている

I think the second part of this sentence is using 「AをBとして認めている」 and it have omitted the object which is obviously the same word 「エンジニア」which appears in the former clause and should be omitted. If I **don't mind being long-winded**, the complete sentence should be:

> 私たちの会社は、従業員のうち、エンジニアは、技術力を持つ重要な存在であるとし、**エンジニアを**経営の基盤として認めている。

Does my analysis make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis seems mostly correct. Just note that は is fundamentally a topic/contrast marker, and it can mark both a subject and an object. So the following *is* a valid sentence:

> 私たちの会社**は**、従業員のうちエンジニア**は**経営の基盤として認めている。

The first は marks the topic of the entire sentence (the subject of 認めている), and the second は marks the object of 認めている (replaced を for emphasis/contrast). Therefore, you may also simply think エンジニアは is a *shared* argument that modifies two verb phrases (重要な存在であるとする and 基盤として認めている).

Comment: Thanks! And do you think 私たちの会社は、エンジニア**は**、技術力を持つ重要な存在であるとする is also from  私たちの会社は、エンジニア**を**、技術力を持つ重要な存在であるとする, which means it's a sentence form of "～を～とする", but not a clause behind と?

Comment: @shepherd Ah, yes, the entire sentence still makes perfect sentence if that は were を. You can read about this [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56540/5010) and [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/56003/5010).

Comment: Thanks! I have read those answers! And do you think my explanation in the question which see 従業員のうち、エンジニアは、技術力を持つ重要な存在である as a whole clause quoted by と and consider the second part to have omitted the object, is also possible?

Comment: @shepherd Yes, both interpretations are possible.