# When do you use the particles "ga" or "wo" for certain adjectives?

Tags: grammar, particles, adjectives

I understand the differences between using "ga" and "wo" for action verbs and static verbs, but what about for adjectives? For example, typically you would say Xが怖い, but I see several cases where it's written Xを怖い (sometimes before something like と思う or と感じる, but sometimes even in these situations it still uses "ga")

Some examples from a Japanese article:

Using "ga"

- 結婚が怖い
- 結婚が怖いと感じる理由を紹介します

Using "wo"

- 結婚を「怖い」と感じる
- 結婚を怖いと思う人
- あなたは結婚するのを怖いと思いますか？

Is it sometimes "wo" when it's part of a phrase or are there any other clear linguistic rules for the difference in usage here?

Comment: 怖い, 好き and so on are special. Please see the accepted answer.

Comment: This may related, too: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55990/5010