# して omitted in として?

Tags: grammar, particle-と, manga

I am reading this manga called Spy x Family; In one of the pages there is a car accident caused by a failure of the car break, resulting in the death of a Diplomat.

Later in a meeting, the following sentence is spoken:

> だが当局は東の極右政党による暗殺と見ている。- But the authorities see it as an assassination by the eastern far right political party.

So my question is: Is して omitted in と見ている？ Or is it a different piece of grammar I am not aware of?

Is it ok to say として見ている or として見られている here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, して is not omitted. 見る is one of the [verbs that take AをB(だ)と](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55169/5010). The following sentences roughly mean the same thing:

- 当局は(この事故を)東の極右政党による暗殺**だと**見ている。
- 当局は(この事故を)東の極右政党による暗殺**と**見ている。
- 当局は(この事故を)東の極右政党による暗殺**として**見ている。

Please see also: [Difference between だと vs と before 認める](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55990/5010)

Comment: So it is basically the same as 「当局は事故を東の極右政党による暗殺だと見ている」right? I did not know about this grammar, thanks a lot!

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Yes, but I don't know if it's fine to say "だ has been omitted" in this case. In English, "to regard it as an assassination" is a complete phrase on its own and it's not a contracted version of "to regard it as *being* an assassination", right? Likewise, I tend to feel それを暗殺と見る is a complete phrase.

Comment: True, makes sense! Thanks again!!