# 〜を。。。だ inside a と言う clause

Tags: particles, copula, subordinate-clauses

In the ASK Graded Reader ゴン狐, the following sentence appears:

> 魚売りは、おれ**を**泥棒**だ**と言って、。。。

I have seen that using を。。。と言う is like saying 'to call somebody something.' My issue is that there is a だ at the end of the clause. I would *expect* it to be either おれが。。。だと or おれを。。。と, but the two together confuses me.

How does this make sense? Would it not be correct to say おれが泥棒だと言った?

Comment: Closely related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55990/5010 and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55158/5010

Answer (score 2):

This 言う is a member of [this verb group](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55158/5010), so だ before と is optional. (This reminds me of the "optional *being*" in English, as in "to regard me as being a thief" vs "to regard me as a thief".)

I would say this type of と is **not** quotative-*to* because the part marked with と is a simple noun (phrase) rather than a sentence.

俺が泥棒だと言って would tend to be taken as "saying 'I am the thief'" (i.e., the 魚売り is calling himself a thief).

Comment: What about 俺に? How would that affect the meaning?

Answer (score 1):

The speaker is saying 'The fishmonger, calling me a thief..". (It seems the line is adapted, but the speaker seems 兵十. [Cf. the original](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000121/files/628_14895.html).）

<strike>と in 泥棒だと言って is clearly 引用の「と」</strike>, and requires a 終止形 ending for the preceding verb (or words that conjugate).

[Edit] Maybe naruto is right - this is not a 引用, but still it requiring a 終止形 should be the same. I found [a seemingly relevant article](http://www.lingua.tsukuba.ac.jp/ippan/TWPL0/TWPL03_29/9_kim.pdf).

Compare:

- その女の子を**かわいい**と言って : saying that the girl is pretty
- その女の子を**きれいだ**と言って : saying that the girl is beautiful
- その女の子を**美少女だ**と言って : saying that the girl is a pretty girl

All the bold words are in 終止形.

===

A simpler (no) explanation is that the acceptable particles are determined by the verb. If this sounds fair enough, just remember it as pattern:

- call N1 N2 = N1**を**N2**と**呼ぶ / N1{**を,が**}N2**だと**言う.

Concretely:

- {俺が泥棒だ,  俺を泥棒だ, ?俺は泥棒だ, ?俺を泥棒}と言って
  are all possible with (?) being less natural, but
- 俺を泥棒と呼んで
  is the only option.

In short, だ in the question exists because いう (tends to) requires it.

===

FYI: ごん狐 is possibly one of the few non-fairy-tale stories that close to everybody knows in Japan  (as long as s/he learned from standard textbooks in primary school).

Comment: While I appreciate the rigour of your response, as a person working on a graded reader targetted at N4 students, this answer is wildly inaccessible.

Comment: See the edit. I admit I cannot give a full explanation. BTW probably you should have included more context so that those who don't know the story can answer.

Comment: I removed largely the first part of the answer. Probably best understood as the verb requiring the use of だ. You should refer to the posts linked in naruto's comment.

Answer (score 0):

魚売りは、おれが泥棒だと言って sounds like the fishmonger is calling themself the thief, which seems a bit unlikely, but as per the comments below, it could be understood as intended too.

In 魚売りは、おれを泥棒だと言って, the quoted part is just 泥棒だ.  If you want to say, *The fishmonger called me a thief* and capture "me" within the quote, then the sentence should have been おまえが泥棒だと言って

Keep in mind that Japanese does not have indirect speech like we do in English.  Japanese only has direct speech, *the fishmonger said, "you're a thief"*

Comment: Without quotation marks and/or further context, I would understand `魚売りは、おれが泥棒だと言って` as meaning the fishmonger said the the speaker was the thief. If I wanted to say the fishmonger declared himself to be the thieve, I would probably say `魚売りは、自分が泥棒だと言って` to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @aguijonazo should i remove the answer then?

Comment: No. I just think the “speaker” in the first line should be “fishmonger”. That interpretation is very much possible. It would be a case of direct speech without quotation marks.

Comment: So then why is this not おれに?  >>He said to me, "you are a thief"?<<

Comment: @frog. I'm not sure why you're asking that. Do you believe おれに is necessary? Japanese is very context dependent and such an addition seems like it would be overkill (even in English, which demands a pedantic insistence on details).

Comment: @A.Ellett How is it overkill? It's already in the sentence, I'm just changing the particle. If it is as you say only direct speech, then the おれ is the audience for the speech, which is very commonly marked with に. If おれ is not the audience, then why isn't it inside the quoted clause?

Comment: @frog: I understand your doubt. I'm a native and I wouldn't have noticed, but `おれを泥棒だと言って` indeed is a strange combination. I just don't know how to explain how we still make sense out of it.

Comment: @frog Again, I'm still not understanding.  I was asking for clarification.  What I said wasn't meant as a criticism.  I'm just explaining why I'm confused.  Sorry if I gave offense.