# 【～が要る】　Is 要る an adjective? Why not を？

Tags: grammar

「要る」をneedと訳してしまうと、どうして「～を要る」にならないのか、わかりません。

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66300/9831

Answer (score 4):

要る is an **intransitive *verb*** that means "to be necessary" or "to be needed" rather than "to need". (No i-adjective ends with る in Japanese.) That's why we mark the needed thing using が rather than を. For example, the very literal translation of お金が要る is "Money is needed", but in English, it's usually more natural to translate this as "[I] need money". Likewise, "要る?" is usually translated as "Do you want/need it?", but its literal translation is "Is it necessary?".

(The link by Chocolate explains a rather exceptional case where 要る is used as part of the [`AをBと + verb` pattern](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55169/5010), but this doesn't mean 要る can take を alone.)

Comment: Thx for explanation!!!btw, what does i-adjective mean?

Comment: @Sheepeagle It's an ordinary adjective that ends with い, such as 赤い, 大きい, etc.