# Parsing sentence: 市立馬堀中学校でプールの給水栓を約２カ月間、断続的に開けたままにしたことで、約４２３万８千リットルの水道水が流出したと発表した。

Tags: grammar

Link: https://www.kanaloco.jp/news/government/article-905621.html

> 横須賀市は２１日、市立馬堀中学校でプールの給水栓を約２カ月間、断続的に開けたままにしたことで、約４２３万８千リットルの水道水が流出したと発表した。

This seems to be a [AをBと construction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55158/can-%e3%82%92-used-with-%e3%81%a0-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99/55169#55169). But parsing it like that gives "It was announced that pool's water tap (in ... school) as ...". So I wonder if this is the correct way to parse to begin with.

Also, how do we parse ままにしたことで? ままに -> while, したこと -> nominalized did, で -> then (???)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added brackets to help you to parse this sentence better,

> 横須賀市は２１日、（市立馬堀中学校でプールの給水栓を約２カ月間、断続的に開けたままにしたことで）、（約４２３万８千リットルの水道水が流出した）と発表した。
>
> On April 21, Yokosuka city announced that about 4,238,000 liters of tap water leaked due to somebody intermittently putting pool's water tap in open state at Mahori Municipal Junior High over the period of about 2 months.

The basic structure is「横須賀市は２１日 ．．．と発表した。」"On April 21, Yokosuka city announced that..."

The first を (プールの給水栓を) actually belongs to the verb 開けた, not 発表した.

> Also, how do we parse ままにしたことで? ままに -> while, したこと -> nominalized did, で -> then (???)?

断続的に開けたままにしたことで is modifying 流出した. こと normalizes the preceding clause「市立馬堀中学校でプールの給水栓を約２カ月間、断続的に開けたままにした」. で describes a means of action.