# What is the grammar behind を being used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-を

> 今のような学歴社会をいいことだとは思っていない日本人もたくさんいる。

What is the grammar behind を being used in this sentence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The structure of this sentence is AをBと思う, meaning "to think of A as B", "regard A as B" etc, where A is 今のような学歴社会 and B is いいことだ.

Putting it together we get something like:

> There are a lot of Japanese who do not regard the current academically focused society as a good thing.

Note that I'm not 100% sure on my translation of 今のような学歴社会.

Comment: Thank you! Is it that this same structure can be used with other verbs as well? It reminds me of AをBとして~ but I haven't seen it in a textbook yet

Comment: @KN Yes! See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55169/5010).