# Correct Particle Usage

Tags: particles

Just wondering about the correct particles in this sentence...

毎朝、何時にうちにでまか。

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: ??? Do you mean うちを[出]{で}ま*す*か?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little vague, but the correct sentence would be

> 毎朝、何時にうち**を**出ますか。　→　What time do you leave your house every morning?

Refer to [Making sense of transitive usage of 行く and 来る - 「を行く」 and 「を来る」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3243/78) for reasoning on why `を` is the correct particle in this case.  The `に` and `か` (and the lack of one after `毎朝`) are all correct as is.