# Sentence structure for complex sentences

Tags: syntax, て-form, particle-から

I've been reading up on the uses of the particle から, particularly when it is appended to the -te form of a verb where it takes on the meaning similar to "after [verb], [sentence 2]"

However, when building this complex sentence I realized I don't really understand how a sentence should be built. 
For example, these are two variations of a sentence I came up with:

> ご飯を食べてから一緒に公園でさんぽしましょ。
>   "After [I] eat breakfast, let's go walk in the park."
>
> ご飯を食べてから公園で一緒にさんぽしましょ。
>   "After [I] eat breakfast, let's go to the park for a walk."

Both of these sentences look correct, but the second sentence doesn't seem natural to me because it mentions the park before the noun "Issho". What would be more proper, and is there a pattern I can follow?

Comment: This sentence should be `...公園 **を** 散歩しました`.  See [Making sense of transitive usage of 行く and 来る - 「を行く」 and 「を来る」](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3243/78) for reasoning.

Comment: Are not both を　and で　correct, as in ジョンは川を／で泳ぐ？(The examples in my dictionary do not use で: they also suggest を can imply 一回りして so perhaps it grammatically correct but not used? )

Comment: Thanks, I guess? But that doesn't really answer my question at all and just raises more questions, seeing as I am still learning the basics of the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the 2nd is natural also. 1st is [一緒に]->[公園で散歩], 2nd is [公園で]->[一緒に散歩].

1st strengthens "in the park", 2nd strengthens "with me".

The pattern is "to place the word *near* a verb, if you want to make the word strongly connected with the verb."

映画を見た後で私と食事をしましょう proposes "to eat" or "to take a lunch", not to go to a park, etc.

映画を見た後で食事を私としましょう proposes "with me", not with other persons.

Answer (score 3):

> ご飯を食べてから一緒に公園で/をさんぽしましょ。
>  
>   ご飯を食べてから公園で/を一緒にさんぽしましょ。

... both sound natural to me and I don't see much difference between them.
You can also say

> ご飯の後で～～
>   ご飯を食べたら～～
>  
>   ～～～一緒に公園にさんぽに行きましょ。
>   etc.