# Transitive meaning of the word "翻る"?

Tags: meaning, verbs, transitivity

I was under the impression that the word 翻る（ひるがえる）is an intransitive verb (which is also how it appears to be defined in dictionaries), but I've come across a use of it that appears to be transitive, in the phrase "今世紀に入ってからの歴史を翻っても…".

My question is, how should the word be interpreted in this context?

Comment: What comes after? If the 翻る is the verb that catches the previous phrase, I must say it's misuse.

Comment: What follows is an independent clause, so the predicate to this phrase is 翻る. If the word has been used incorrectly, perhaps the author might have meant something like 振り返る?

Comment: Yes, that's what I suspect. Or perhaps the author has mixed it up with 繙く【ひもとく】.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel 翻る here is used as a motion verb, which [often takes を even though it's intransitive](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3243/5010). Perhaps the author intended to mean "go over / go through (a document, etc) again" by saying 翻る. I wouldn't say it's a common usage, but I wouldn't call it a definitive mistake, either.

As you can see in [these examples](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/188657/example/m0u/), 翻って考える is a common idiom that literally means "turn back and think over again", and 翻って on its own can mean the same thing.