# What is the difference between 急ぐ{いそぐ} and 急かす{せかす}?

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances, verbs

The verbs 急ぐ{いそぐ} and 急かす{せかす} both seem to mean *to hurry*. Is there any difference between them?

Also, Jisho.org says that 急ぐ can be both intransitive and transitive, but doesn't mention the transitivitiy of 急かす at all, which I find particularly weird (for all other verbs I've seen on Jisho, their transitivity was always mentioned). Is 急かす transitive or intransitive (or both)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

急かす【せかす】 is transitive, and usually takes a person as an object.

> - 彼を急かした。 I hurried him. / I made him hurry.
> - そんなに(俺を)急かすなよ。 Don't rush me so much.

急ぐ【いそぐ】 is usually intransitive, but it also sometimes takes [を as a location marker](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3243/5010). 急ぐ also has a transitive usage, and when 急ぐ is transitive, it takes an inanimate object.

> - 私は今、急いでいます。 I'm in a hurry now.
> - この道を急ぎましょう。 Let's hurry in this way.
> - プロジェクトの完成を急ごう。 Let's hurry to complete the project.

Etymologically, I believe 急かす【せかす】 is one of the causative forms of 急く【せく】, which is another rare intransitive verb meaning *to hurry*. It's the same as the "shortened causative form" explained [here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/causepass), but 急かす is far more common in 急く today. 急く is found almost only in [this proverb](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%80%A5%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF%E4%BA%8B%E3%82%92%E4%BB%95%E6%90%8D%E3%81%9A%E3%82%8B). I think you can regard 急かす as a separate (transitive) verb.

Comment: Tae Kim seems misunderstanding that short causative forms are shortened from the longer ones.

Comment: Thank you very much, great answer. The examples were very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

According to Weblio, 急かす is a transitive verb, with 急く being the intransitive form. As far as the difference in meaning, there doesn't seem to be any, though I would venture to guess that 急ぐ is the more common usage.