# How do these two を relate to the respective verbs?

Tags: grammar

For full context:
https://www.satorireader.com/articles/sanzu-no-kawa-episode-1-edition-m?sentenceID=SrOvSLFfSOyCJFzmEmFt

Sentence in question:
そこを、対向車線を走る車が、もうスピードですれちがっていく

=> "vehicles, which drive there (=this road) on the opposite lane, pass by with extreme speed."

There are 2 を which both connect the noun to an intransitive verb expressing movement.
This use of を is always a bit confusing to me, So I just wanted to ask for confirmation wether I got it right or not. Especially the first を in そこを gives me a headache. 
そこ clearly refers to the 高速道路 from before, but I'm not so sure wether the first を attaches to すれちがっていく or 走る? I think a relation to 走る would make more sense.

Furthermore, I'm not sure about why in ちがっていく , 行く or 来る should be used at all? AFAIK they usually indicate that something is moving towards or away from the speaker. If the verb is used in this function here, then I wonder why 行く should be preferred over 来る in this context. After all, the object passing by first needs to approach you and then move away from you again.

Comment: After Futhermore ちがっていく → すれちがっていく？ you have すれちがっていく before.

Comment: "すれちがっていく": "the cars are passing" is natural here. "ちがっていく " could mean "the cars running in the same lane branching off".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Yes this そこ refers to the 高速道路.
- Both of the two を are [location markers used with intransitive verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3243/5010). そこを modifies the main verb すれ違っていく. 対向車線を modifies 走る in a relative clause that modifies 車. As far as I understand, one verb can never take more than one を.
- すれ違っていく is [すれ違う](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3243/5010) followed by a [subsidiary verb 行く](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010) that describes some physical/emotional movement away from the speaker. In this case, 行く is a neutral choice that simply expresses cars going away from the speaker after the action of すれ違う. すれ違ってくる ("coming close to pass me") focuses on the approaching cars, and it would sound as if the speaker is scared by every car on the opposite lane. I know this paragraph is about the anxiety of the speaker, but すれ違っていく itself is used to describe an objective fact.

Comment: ここは、中央分離帯のない山道だから”すれ違っていく”のだと思いました。普通の高速道路をすれ違っていくと言うのは不自然だと少し思ったんですが。動揺してしまいました。もちろん解釈に違いがある事に異論があるって言う訳ではないです笑

Comment: @kimiTanaka 文法的に「それ」が何を指すのかと言われたら、普通は単純に前の文の話題である「（この）高速道路」と答えればいいのでは…。世の中の高速道路一般の話をしている文脈でないのは明らかですし。

Comment: 意味的には、中央分離帯があるので距離的に車が反対車線を走っているのをすれ違っているのは違和感があったので、友達とすれ違ってと言えば挨拶をしたと解釈するのが自然かなと思いました。単に距離があるから見たと言うよりは。文法上の解釈に対して異論があると言う訳では無いので確認と言うだけです。失礼致しました。

Comment: 確かに、OPの文のも"the"高速道路 from beforeって書いてありますね。改めて失礼致しました。なぜだか知らないですけど、文の右端を良く見落とします。