# Use of を生きる applied to a non-living thing

Tags: meaning

お父さんと一緒の時間を生きる事が命を受け取るって事なんだ。

I don't understand the "を生きる" being applied to a non-living thing like the time you spent with your dad.

The "が命を受け取るって事なんだ" extends the first sentence into another part before I can even understand the ending of the first part?

How do you break it down?

Comment: Are you familiar with the end-of-sentence construction ということだ in a definition or "X is a kind of Y" statement? I believe って事なんだ is just another way of expressing the same thing.

Comment: This を before 生きる is a [sort of location particle](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3243/5010).

Comment: Helpful suggestion everyone thank you all!. Interesting read naruto. I think I've heard it before mamster but not familiar with the meaning and the contraction didn't help to make it simpler to spot. Also the verbiage confused me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「お父{とう}さんと一緒{いっしょ}の時間{じかん}を生{い}きる事{こと}**が**命{いのち}を受{う}け取{と}る**って事**なんだ。」

This sentence is in a very simple construct of:

> "Phrase A + **が** + Phrase B + という/っていう/って + **こと** + だ/なんだ/です/である"

which means:

> "Phrase A means none other than Phrase B."

A = "making the most of my time with my dad"

B = "taking the baton of life"

「～～**を**生きる」 means "to make the most of ~~".  We often say 「今{いま}を生きる」、「現在{げんざい}を生きる」, etc.  A cool expression to know.

> "To make the most of my time with my dad means (none other than) to take the baton of life (from him)."

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down so nicely for me! You answered the points I needed help with and added in extra help along the way as well. Very helpful answer! The bolding is also a nice touch!