# What does "やればいける” mean?

Tags: translation

Context is 2 friends talking with each other after a night of drinking. The other friend drunk called her ex-boyfriend. The other friend said this.

> だから言{い}ったっしょ
>
> 酒入{さけい}れてガーッとやればいけるって

Is this the same to やれば出来る? I'm also not sure how ガーッと is used here.

Like "You can do it if you're drunk."

Comment: Could you add a few more sentences before this? It's hard to guess what this だから refers to, and that's important.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65737/5010

Answer (score 1):

Context is severely lacking, and I have no idea what this だから refers to, or what they are actually talking about. Still, I can say this sentence has nothing to do with the idiom やればできる. This やる is part of ガーっとやる described [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65737/5010).

- 酒を入れる = "to take alcohol" or "to make someone take alcohol"
- ガーッとやる = "to do (something) vigorously/swiftly/strongly"
- いける = "will go well", "can do it", "will be okay"

So the translation should be "If you drink alcohol and do it strongly, it'll be fine" or "If you make him drink and do it in one go, you can do it", or something along these lines.

Comment: 回答内の"If you make **him** drink and do it in one go, you can do it" に対して、質問者の'The other friend drunk called **her ex-boyfriend**. ' なので女性同士の会話なのでしょうか？

Answer (score -1):

だから言ったでしょ means “I said that!”
“that” is 酒入れてガーッとやればいける
だから is used here like “you know”

いける can mean “ taste good”, “can”, “flirt with someone” or “persuade someone”.

Here I write possible meanings of 酒入れてガーッとやればいける.

> If you mix it with alcohol drink, it will taste good. (ガーッ is mix)
>   If you drink alcohol strongly, you can do it. (ガーッ is strongly)
>   If you let her drink alcohol and try hard, you can flirt with her.(ガーッ is try hard)
>   If you drink alcohol and explain roughly, you can persuade him.(ガーッ is explain roughly)