# Why is the particle を instead of で used for the verb 歩き回る?

Tags: particle-を, particle-で

Why is the particle を used for the verb 歩き回る instead of で?

Some examples from Tatoeba:

> 足に任せて町の中を歩き回った。

> 時間つぶしに、私達は公園を歩き回った。

Why does it not follow the [location で verb] pattern? I couldn't find an example using the particle で. Would saying 公園で歩き回った be grammatically incorrect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making sense of transitive usage of 行く and 来る - 「を行く」 and 「を来る」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/making-sense-of-transitive-usage-of-%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%8f-and-%e6%9d%a5%e3%82%8b-%e3%82%92%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%8f-and-%e3%82%92%e6%9d%a5%e3%82%8b)  In particular, look at the second answer.  It seems I've seen a few other similar questions.  I'll see if I can find them.

Comment: @A.Ellett That does answer my question! Thanks you.