# "原チャで５分の距離を通院もした" The direct object of 通院 is ５分の距離?

Tags: grammar, sentence

> 先月には、初めて手術ってのも経験した。退院後は、原チャで５分の距離を通院もした。

I think that me not knowing what ５分の距離 means and assuming that it means "distance of 5 minutes with my moped", but I somehow perceive it that 距離 is the thing that is being 通院 and not the speaker

I tried finding sentences that have a direct object with 通院 but I can't find any.

Here is my understanding of the sentence

> The distance of 5 minutes with my moped is (used to go to the) hospital for regular checkups

Comment: This seems related: [Making sense of transitive usage of 行く and 来る - 「を行く」 and 「を来る」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3243/43676)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not impossible to think 原チャで5分の距離 as the object of 通院する. English also has *travel a distance*.

According to a [dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%92/#jn-239138), を can mean

> ３ 移動の意を表す動詞に応じて、動作の経由する場所を示す。…を通って。「山道を行く」「廊下を走る」「山を越す」
>
> ４ 動作・作用の持続する時間を示す。「長い年月を過ごす」「日々を送る」 ,

so that the usage in question is something in between (or simply 3). It means the distance associated with the motion verb.

So 原チャで５分の距離を通院もした means *I went on a regular basis to the hospital which is a 5-minute ride by moped away*.

---

Some other examples

- 電車で2時間の距離を毎日通学した = 毎日電車で2時間かけて通学した *went to school every day and it took 2 hours by train*.
- 歩いて10分の距離を車で移動した *used a car to travel the distance of a 10 minute walk*.