に or を？Grammar help
In the sentence トムはそのときこうえんをあるいていた how come you use を instead of に for こうえん? Is it because grammarly the park can not do something to someone? I read something about intransitive and transitive verbs as well. Is it something like that?

Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3243/5010

Many intransitive verbs of movement can use “〜を” to signify the medium through which one moves, this is not really the direct object and can't for instance be turned into the passive like a true direct object but it works:

空を飛ぶ -> fly through the sky
公園を歩く -> walk through/in a park
歩道を歩く -> walk on the pavement
町を歩き回る -> walk about town
海を泳ぐ -> swim in the ocean/sea

Intransitive verbs of movement generally use “〜に” to mark their destination not the medium of movement but there are exceptions to this such as your “歩く” which cannot do this for whatever reason. We cannot say “公園に歩く” to mean “walk to the park”, we must say “公園へ”, “公園に向かって”, “公園まで” or whatever else.
